# Why wget fails with 'https: Host not found' on Windows?

Tags: windows, download, wget, redirection

I'm trying to use wget on Windows 8.1 prompt. I installed wget.exe in the folder System32 and run wget on cmd. But the following error appear:

```
M:\site>wget http://wordpress.org/latest.zip
--15:44:37--  http://wordpress.org:80/latest.zip
       => `latest.zip'
Connecting to wordpress.org:80... connected!
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://wordpress.org/latest.zip [following]
--15:44:37--  ftp://https:21/%2Fwordpress.org/latest.zip
       => `latest.zip'
Connecting to https:21...
https: Host not found
```

Comment: Cross-posted: [wget on Windows return error](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29581742/55075) at stackoverflow

Comment: Which version of wget are you using?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like:

- your `wget` is old and buggy,
- it doesn't have HTTPS support,
- server sends a malformed redirection.

So it's treating `https://foo` as if it matched the `host:path` shorthand syntax for ftp URLs.

So if this command fails for older versions of wget, try to upgrade your `wget`.

The more recent versions of wget should recognize it at least as an unsupported scheme.

Alternatively use `curl`, for example:

```
curl -O http://wordpress.org/latest.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [GNU WGet](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm) the following command worked after I got a message about a certificate error:

```
wget --no-check-certificate "http://wordpress.org/latest.zip"
```

Using a [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/download.html) version with SSL support also works:

```
curl --insecure "https://wordpress.org/latest.zip" -o wplatest.zip
```